# Send data to BLE sensor device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors

I'm using this code from google to connect to a Bosch XDK Sensor:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt

The connection works fine, but for the sensor to start streaming I need to send a command (0x7374617274) to it. I'm kinda lost as how to do that. Is it possible with the sample app?

```
public boolean writeCharacteristic(){
    //check mBluetoothGatt is available
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "lost connection");
        return false;
    }

    BluetoothGattService Service = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("b9e875c0-1cfa-11e6-b797-0002a5d5c51b"));
    if (Service == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "service not found!");
        return false;
    }
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac = Service
            .getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("1ed9e2c0-266f-11eb-850b-0002a5d5c51b"));
    if (charac == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "char not found!");
        return false;
    }

    byte[] value = hexStringToByteArray("0x7374617274");
    charac.setValue(value);
    boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(charac);
    return status;
 }
```

Comment: Are you trying peripheral or central mode?

Comment: Sorry, don't really know what that means. I have found an example for a writeCharateristics function. But the service I'm trying to write is null although it is discovered before. I added the function in the original post.

Comment: There are characteristics and services https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Comment: The characteristics you requested is not on that chip you get null value. So please recheck the chara and read again

Comment: Got it working now, had the wrong characteristic.